# OptimisticConcurrencyException EF6 - find causing entity properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I spent half a day, trying to figure out, what is causing the OptimisticConcurrencyException in my code. Now althtough I did finally find the cause, I was wondering, if there is a way, that could possibly save me a ton of work next time.

My problem coud have been found very easily, if I had known, what properties are different from my context instance.

Is there a way to get this from the OptimisticConcurrencyException object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what your problem really is, but I've solved some concurrency issues in the past using rowversion.

Comment: The problem is, I have two classes, instantiating their own context but operating on the samy entity. And if I had seen, what properties were the cause of the concurrency (because they modified the same properties of the entity) I would have found out, that there is a second context instance, the other class is operating on.